# Getting the added gridview table data on the code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a gridview on my aspx (designer) file. I have added the rows through the generated gridview table through javascript to make the web more performance friendly, and I update the whole table using a save button. But I am not able to get the added rows on my code behind. Is there anyway for the browser to communicate that(new rows) to the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

not an easy way - the server (code behind) doesn't know about any rows inserted by your javascript - so when you post back to the server, the rows are gone.
one solution would be:

1. Put your data in a server-known input-control, like a `HiddenField` in a serialized form.
2. Post back to your server and deserialize the data
3. Add the desirialized data to your gridview on the server